# problems with datetime c#

Tags: c#, timezone, utc

In my work, I create a form which will be used for Outlook(it will be a plugin). In my form user can choose meeting date and time. When the user has filled out the form message is send. I then my problem starts.

For example: Even when I choose 1:30 p.m   in my form the message send to another user show that the meeting will start at 3:30 p.m. 
To create my plugin I had to use TMS.
API documentation says that I need to use UTC time. 
In my country, UTC is UTC+1 and now we are dealing with Summertime so we have GMT+2.
My problem is that in the message the meeting time is +2 hours relative to the time of the meeting indicated in the form.

My code is:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo;
DateTime dateTime;

timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2), timeZoneInfo);

string sessionID = "";
string startTime = "";
string endTime = "";

dateTime = dateTimePicker3.Value;

x_workers api = new x_workers();
yworker gui = new xworker();
sessionID = gui.generateSessionId();

startTime = dateTimePicker.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") +" "+ dateTime.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
endTime = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") + " " + dateTimePicker4.Value.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
```

I also try:

```
string sessionID = "";
string startTime = "";
string endTime = "";

api_workers api = new api_workers();
guiWorkers gui = new guiWorkers();
sessionID = gui.generateSessionId();

startTime = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") +" "+ dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
endTime = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd") + " " + dateTimePicker4.Value.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
```

And i second option I have only extra 1 hour.

What should I do?

Comment: Carl279 i tried your solution and in my case it doesn't work, but thanks for help.

Comment: Each `DateTime` value carries a `.Kind` property that you can check. You can use the simple instance methods `.ToUniversalTime()` and `.ToLocalTime()` to create another `DateTime` value with the other kind. You can then go on to call `.ToString(format)`. The actual time zone _is not_ encoded in the `DateTime` value. The interpretation of "local" is the time zone used by the OS of the machine.

Comment: Hi.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your example is not complete, as we have no idea what your `dateTimePicker/1/2/3/4` controls are, or the values that are coming out of them.  Also you have a lot of other items (api, gui, session, etc.) that are not relevant to your question.  Additionally, note that in your first example you are reassigning `dateTime` to the value of your picker, so anything you may have previously assigned it to is lost and thus irrelevant to the output.

Comment: Additionally note that by appending a `Z` literal to your strings, you are asserting that those are UTC times.  Your statement "In my country, UTC is UTC+1" is nonsensical, as UTC is always just UTC.  Also, you say something about "TMS" but are not clear what that is exactly.

Comment: Perhaps what you need to do is to convert your local time to UTC before posting your form then? see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915(v=vs.110).aspx